# how can i parse data from the url from one activity containing using a list view to another activity according to these codes?

Tags: android-listview

```
package list.of.products;



        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        import android.app.ListActivity;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
        import android.net.NetworkInfo;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import android.view.View;

        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.ProgressBar;

        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.MainActivity;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.R;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.adapter.HalalAdapter;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.httpmanager.HttpManager;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.model.HalalModel;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.parser.HalalParser;

public class ListOfProducts extends ListActivity {

    private static final String PHOTOS_BASE_URL = "http://huxy.byethost15.com/Products/";
    public ListView ListOfProduct;
    TextView output;
    ProgressBar pb;
    List<MyTask> tasks;
    public ListView ListOfProducts;
    List<HalalModel> flowerList;

    private HalalAdapter adapter;
    public static HalalParser mUserClicked;



    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listofproducts);


        //list view of the products
        ListOfProducts = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Button list = (Button) findViewById(R.id.list);
        Button back =(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      //listview


        this.ListOfProduct =(ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ListOfProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.ListOfProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                   //please what can i put here according to  my codes



                    Intent i = new Intent(ListOfProducts.this,
                            Details.class);

                    startActivity(i);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });



    /* progress bar /
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    }




//back button


    public void Back(View v){
        Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(ListOfProducts.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    //button for fetching
    public void list(View view){

         try {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             if (view.getId() == R.id.list) {
 // butto is requesting data from the url

                 if (isOnline()) {
                     requestData("http://huxy.byethost15.com/halal.php");


                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                             .show();
                 }


             }
         }
         catch (Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     "Network isn't available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                     .show();
         }
         }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    protected void updateDisplay() {
        // Use FlowerAdapter to display data
        HalalAdapter adapter = new HalalAdapter(this, R.layout.listofproducts,
                flowerList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected boolean isOnline() {
```

// this method shows network connectivity
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

```
    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<HalalModel>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            tasks.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<HalalModel> doInBackground(String... params) {

            String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0], "feeduser",
                    "feedpassword");
            flowerList = HalalParser.parseFeed(content);

            for (HalalModel product : flowerList) {
                try {
                    String imageUrl = PHOTOS_BASE_URL + product.getId();
                    InputStream in = (InputStream) new URL(imageUrl)
                            .getContent();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    product.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return flowerList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HalalModel> result) {

            tasks.remove(this);
            if (tasks.size() == 0) {
                pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if (result == null) {
                Toast.makeText(ListOfProducts.this, "Web service not available",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            flowerList = result;
            updateDisplay();

        }

    }

}




// another class HalalModel

package com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.model;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by HUZY-KAMZ on 7/27/2015.
 */
public class HalalModel {

    private String Id;
    private String ProductName ;
    private String Pbox;
    public String Images;

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return ProductName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        ProductName = productName;
    }

    public String getPbox() {
        return Pbox;
    }

    public void setPbox(String pbox) {
        Pbox = pbox;
    }

    public String getImages() {
        return Images;
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        Images = images;
    }
}



// another class HalalParse
package com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.parser;

        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.model.HalalModel;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;





public class HalalParser {

    public static List<HalalModel> parseFeed(String content) {

        try {
            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(content);
            List<HalalModel> flowerList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < ar.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);
                HalalModel product = new HalalModel();


                product.setId(obj.getString("Id"));
                product.setProductName(obj.getString("ProductName"));
                product.setPbox(obj.getString("Pbox"));




                flowerList.add(product);
            }

            return flowerList;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }
}

// another class HalalAdapter
package com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.adapter;


        import java.util.List;



        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.R;
        import com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.model.HalalModel;


public class HalalAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HalalModel> {

    private Context context;
    private List<HalalModel> flowerList;

    public HalalAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<HalalModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.flowerList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.productslist, parent, false);

        //Display flower name in the TextView widget
        HalalModel product = flowerList.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.YOURTVID);
        TextView tv2 =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        tv.setText(product.getProductName());
        tv2.setText(product.getPbox());

        //Display flower photo in ImageView widget
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(product.getBitmap());

        return view;
    }

}
// This is my HttpManager Class
package com.example.huzy_kamz.halaalproject.halal.httpmanager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;

public class HttpManager {

    public static String getData(String uri) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static String getData(String uri, String userName, String password) {

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection con = null;

        byte[] loginBytes = (userName + ":" + password).getBytes();
        StringBuilder loginBuilder = new StringBuilder()
                .append("Basic ")
                .append(Base64.encodeToString(loginBytes, Base64.DEFAULT));

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.addRequestProperty("Authorization", loginBuilder.toString());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                int status = con.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("HttpManager", "HTTP response code: " + status);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    }





    public JSONArray GetCustomerDetails(int CustomerID){

        String url = "http://huxykam.byethost31.com/cafe.php";
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        if (httpEntity != null) {
            try {
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                Log.e("Entity Response", entityResponse);
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return jsonArray;






    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `view` parameter you get in the click callback is the view you constructed for the item in your adapter. Therefore you could get a hold of your `TextView`s with `view.findViewById(...)` and get your data that way - so you could stick it into the intent that you send to the other activity (`intent.putExtra(...)`)

Note: I suggest you take a look at the `ViewHolder` pattern for using in your adapter so that you allow the system to recycle your views.

The `ViewHolder` pattern is really simple, you could get from countless places, including Android samples shipped with the SDK. The short version is: Android is not going to create as many Views as list items there are in the adapter. Views are recycled(reused) under the hood. But we need to allow it as well. You need to define the `ViewHolder` class (in the adapter):

```
public static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView tv;
    public TextView tv2;
    public ImageView image;
}
```

And change the getView method to something like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.productslist, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.YOURTVID);
        viewHolder.tv2 =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Display flower name in the TextView widget
    HalalModel product = flowerList.get(position);
    viewHolder.tv.setText(product.getProductName());
    viewHolder.tv2.setText(product.getPbox());
    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(product.getBitmap());

    return convertView;
}
```

Relating to your original request, you can access your clicked data like this:

```
this.ListOfProduct.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            //please what can i put here according to  my codes
            HalalAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            // access your data here:
            // viewHolder.tv
            // viewHolder.tv2
            // ...

            Intent i = new Intent(ListOfProducts.this, Details.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Am new in android world.....so some of the terms are also new.....can you please modify my code or elaborate more...you also share with me any sample of code relating with my codes.......thank you in advance.....